# MySQL JSON datatype to store historical price

Tags: mysql, mysql-json

I am thinking about possible solution to save historical data prices in MySQL 5.7+ with JSON datatype instead of adding new row per historical price.

**Case description:** 
I have a table of products current prices and product description called "Products". Products prices can change after a few days, i want to save the historical price changes using JSON array:

**JSON Base structure:**

```
 PriceChangeDate (date)
 PriceChanged (float)
 PromoType (tinyint) 
 PromoDesc (nvarchar(50))
```

The idea is to save historical data into a separated table called "HistoricalProductPrices" that includes ProductID, (Relation to "Products" table) , DateCreated and a JSON datatype for ProductID history prices with the fields i described.

In some cases i will need whole data history of a product so i will just fetch whole JSON and display for report. Sometimes i will need a specific date or range of product historical price so i guess i will just fetch historical data from JSON and look for deified "PriceChangeDate". 
This will also allow me to save tons of daily insert, instead i will need to update JSON with the new data of products.

What do you guys think about this method to save historical data?

Comment: No, I don't understand why you'd do that. What's wrong with just storing the date and the price?

Comment: I am talking about situation  where prices can change daily and i need to save the historical prices with date of change.

Comment: Why necessarily json. You can, just give it a try with 5.7 . I wouldn't. Mainly because I am sure it would not scale as well and is less tweakable. But go for it.

Comment: Just looking for a way to be able to save each new price change in the same row and not create a new row every price change. It could be JSON or something else?

Comment: Yes. So am I. What's wrong with a new row every time?

Answer (score 1):

You asked:

> What do you guys think about this method to save historical data?

With respect, I think it's a terrible idea. If you do this with MySQL or  any other RDMS, the next person who has to work on your code will stick nails in a puppet that looks like you.  Seriously.

Adding new rows for new events (like a stock trade) or new days is what RDMSs do. They do it very well indeed.

The entire point of a SQL database is to allow rapid updating, searching and aggregating of data in many columns. RDMS systems can store and search millions upon millions of rows of data without breaking a sweat. To put many records together in a single BLOB is to defeat all that search technology.

If you really want to use JSON documents for storage, you may want to investigate MongoDB. It has indexing that works inside some JSON documents.